# How change Layout by default?

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, c#-2.0

I change Layout by default in _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout-empty";
}
```

But it is layout does not work. _Layout is working.

Then I delete _Layout and get error:

> InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be
> located. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Home/_Layout.en.cshtml /Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/_Layout.en.cshtml /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/_Layout.en.cshtml /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

I set breakepoint in _ViewStart and it does not active:

[image]

Why does not _ViewStart.cshtml work and does not change layout?

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be located. The following locations were searched: /Views/Home/_Layout.en.cshtml /Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml /Views/Shared/_Layout.en.cshtml /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml /Pages/Shared/_Layout.en.cshtml /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

The error means it is looking for _Layout.cshtml.And you can set layout gloabaly in _ViewStart.cshtml.Also,you can set it in the view.And the setting in the view will be prior to the setting in _ViewStart.cshtml.

So you need to make sure the view you displayed in browser doesn't contain the following code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Comment: I set Layout in view. First, _Layout-empty works and then it search _Layout. Then I get error

Comment: `then it search _Layout. Then I get error`How do you search _Layout,there is no route to access it directly.